# Flask - Changes made to the css file doesn't get reflected on the browser

Tags: css, flask

I am using Flask to write the webpage. I have made some changes in the css file. The changes are not reflected on the browser.

I have tried changing the background-color of the body of the webpage, but still it loads the old value set to the `background-color`.

```
body {
      background-color: blue;
}
```

The background color should have changed to `blue` but still it appears to be `lightgray` which was the initial value given to `background-color`.

Comment: Their could be several causes. 1st, is your CSS loaded? Then, is it after the old/default one? Finally does the old one have rules that could override your new one such as body {background-color: lightgray!important;}?

Comment: Try hard refresh with control f5.